# How to update data in stack bar chart in D3

Tags: d3.js, stacked

I am able to populate a stacked bar chart first time, but my requirement is to update the stacked  bar chart with new data on button click. On button click, i m making call to backend and getting the data, Could you please guide me as how to update the stacked bar char chart. My problem is passing the new data to bar chart.

```
 d3.json("http://myhost/ITLabourEffortChart/effort/effort",function(error, data){
    color.domain(d3.keys(data.effort[0]).filter(function(key) { 
        return key !== "qName"; }));
data.effort.forEach(function(d) {
var y0 = 0;
d.effortHr = color.domain().map(function(name) { 
    return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });

d.total = d.effortHr[d.effortHr.length - 1].y1;


});
x.domain(data.effort.map(function(d) { return d.qName; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data.effort, function(d) { 
    return d.total; })]);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("FTE");

var state = svg.selectAll(".layer")
  .data(data.effort)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.qName) + ",0)"; });

 rect = state.selectAll("rect")
 .attr("id", "barchart") 
  .data(function(d) { 
      return d.effortHr; })
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { 
      return y(d.y1); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });


On Update i am calling below method
function redraw() {
    d3.json("http://localhost:8080/ITLabourEffortChart/effort/effort/YrReports",function(error, data){

        color.domain(d3.keys(data.effort[0]).filter(function(key) {

            return key !== "qName"; }));
    data.effort.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { 
        return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
    });

     var updatebar = svg.selectAll("#barchart");
    // Update…
     updatebar
     .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
  .transition()
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { 
      return y(d.y1); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); }
  .attr("x", function(d) { 
    return x(d.x); })

  );

    });
  .attr("x", function(d) { 
    return x(d.x); })

  );

    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To update your data you will just need to select the svg elements again and rebind the data. In your example you are already selecting the `#barchart`, now you just need to rebind the data. And you can do that in the same way you did it when you first created the svg Elements. So something like this should do the trick:

```
var updatebar = svg.selectAll("#barchart");
.data(newdata)
.transition()
.duration(500)
... (etc.)
```

Here you can find a more detailed explaination:
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch09.html#_updating_data

Update:

Ok, unfortunately I cannot use Fiddle so I just post my working code here. As far as I could see you have a problem with your selectAll, because there is no element called `.effort`. Here is the updated code for your redraw-function:

```
function redraw() {

    var effort = [];
    var obj = {
        pfte: "20",
        efte: "50",
        qName: "Q1"
    };
    var obj2 = {
        pfte: "10",
        efte: "13",
        qName: "Q2"
    };

    effort[0] = obj;
    effort[1] = obj2;
    var newDataSet = new Object();
    newDataSet.effort = effort;

    color.domain(d3.keys(newDataSet.effort[0]).filter(function (key) {
        return key !== "qName";
    }));

    effortDataSet = newDataSet.effort;
    effortDataSet.forEach(function (d) {
        var y0 = 0;
        d.effortHr = color.domain().map(function (name) {
            return { name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name] };
        });
        d.total = d.effortHr[d.effortHr.length - 1].y1;
    });

    state = svg.selectAll(".g")
        .data(effortDataSet)
        .attr("class", "g")
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d.qName) + ",0)"; });

    state = state.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function (d) {
            return d.effortHr;
        })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.y1);
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
        //console.log(y(d.y0) - y(d.y1));
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
        })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.name); });
}
```

Comment: I have created stacked bar chart like this
[Stacked chart][1]


  [1]: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3886208

But i want to update the data in this chart. My data set changes with axis name and value both.
But i am not able to just achieve the simple data change.
Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is as follows: You first bind a dataset to your elements. That means that your data is **copied** to your elements. Next you use data to get sub-data from your original data (d.effortHr). Inbetween you changed the dataset but the data which is bound to your elements is still the same because it was copied. Try to really rebind the dataset after you changed it again with .data(effortDataSet)

Comment: I am able to redraw the new value but Old bars are not getting removed, its just overlapping on old value.                 var block = state.selectAll("rect")
       .data(function(d) { return d.effortHr; }); 
  
  block.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { 
     return y(d.y1); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
  
  //block.exit().attr("transform", function(d) {console.log(d); return "translate(" + x(d.qName) + ",0)"; }).remove();
  block.exit().remove();

Comment: Make sure you handle two separate steps: 1) Initial step where you create your svg elements with your initial data. 2) Update step where you rebind the data (which has changed). I think you have a problem with your select.

Comment: I forgot: Make sure that in your update-step you do **not enter or append** again. Your elements are already there so you just need to update their data and change the attributes again with the new values...

Comment: Appreciate your answer. I have created a Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9UfT2/2/).I am able to update but not able to remove, If i dont use enter/append, data is not getting updated.Thanks for your help.