# How to update and draw stacked bar chart with new dataset in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

New here. I'm working with D3 and basically I have 2 datasets in the form of arrays. What I want to achieve is upon button click, the new dataset overwrites the old one (I have achieved this much) and then the new dataset is bound and redraws the stacked bar charts. This doesn't happen for me. When the button is pressed it just deletes a couple of the bars.

Would appreciate any tips. I think it's awkward because I'm working with stacked bar charts and not normal ones. 
Thanks! :)

```
         var yAxis = d3.svg.axis() 
                .scale(yScale)
                  .orient("left")
                //  .ticks(5);

        //Width and height
        var w = 600;
        var h = 300;
        var barPadding = 50;



        //Original data
        var dataset = [
            [
                { y: 20 },   //male 
                { y: 4 },
                { y: 16},
                { y: 53},
                { y: 15 }
            ],
            [
                { y: 12 },   //female
                {  y: 4 },
                {  y: 3 },
                {  y: 36 },
                {  y: 2 }
            ],

        ];
        console.log(dataset);





     //    var myDataSet = dataset; 

    //    var totalDeaths = d.y0 + d.y1;

        //Set up stack method
        var stack = d3.layout.stack();

        //Data, stacked
        stack(dataset);

        //Set up scales
        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].length))
            .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0,             
                d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
                    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
                        return d.y0 + d.y;
                    });
                })
            ])
            .range([0, h]);

        //Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
    //  var colors = d3.scale.category20c();

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["Male", "Female"])
  .range(["#00B2EE", "#FF69B4"]);




        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        // Add a group for each row of data
        var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
            });



        // Add a rect for each data value
        var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d) { return d; })
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i);
            })

        .on("mouseover", function(d) {

                //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
                var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
                var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + 14;

                //Create the tooltip label
                svg.append("text")
                   .attr("id", "tooltip")
                   .attr("x", xPosition)
                   .attr("y", yPosition)
                   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                   .attr("font-size", "11px")
                   .attr("font-weight", "bold")
                   .attr("fill", "black")
                   .html("Female deaths: " + d.y + "\n" + "              \nMale deaths: " + d.y0);

           })
           .on("mouseout", function() {

                //Remove the tooltip
                d3.select("#tooltip").remove();

                })



            .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())


           .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y) ;
           })

           .attr("height", function(d) {
                return yScale(d.y);
           });




          d3.select("#target")
            .on("click", function() {       //event listener on button click
   //   alert("heeeey");





                //New values for dataset
            dataset =   [
            [
                { y: 100 },   //male 
                { y: 20 },
                { y: 16},
                { y: 53},
                { y: 15 }
            ],
            [
                { y: 5 },   //female
                {  y: 4 },
                {  y: 3 },
                {  y: 36 },
                {  y: 2 }
            ],

        ]; 

              console.log(dataset);



        //Data, stacked
    //  stack(dataset);



                //Update all rects
        var gas = svg.selectAll("rect")


               .data(dataset)

               //  .transition()
             //   .duration(1000)
            //    .ease("cubic-in-out")
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())


           .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y) ;
           })

           .attr("height", function(d) {
                return yScale(d.y);
           })


              .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i);
            });
          });
```

Comment: You just need to re-set `g`, `rect`, scales, and layout with the updated dataset. Here is a [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/lEJs2xcUD7S5Nz20t7v5?p=preview) to help you out.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186011/how-to-update-data-in-stack-bar-chart-in-d3

Comment: Hi mate, thanks but that PLUNK link doesn't work. You sure that's the one?

Comment: Wait, I think it's the site in general that's down. Hopefully it'll be back up soon. I can use all the help I can get code-wise. I still can't figure out how to do what you're saying. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that worked!! 
Thanks so much. You've saved me hours. 

I'll probably be back soon with more problems, but thanks so much. :)